# Does C++ insertion operator (<<) modified value?

Tags: c++

I have a function that returns an array of double.  In my debugger I insect the array and see that it's values are {6.5, 1.5}.  However,  When I print the array to cout I see, "6.5,3.30525e+230,".  My guess is that either the << is altering my values or I'm not properly formatting

```
double *result;

result = haar1d(series, 2, seriesAverage);
```

--> At a break point here I see result[0] == 6.5 and result[1] == 1.5

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cout << result[i] << ",";
}
```

**Fixed**: Here's what I ended up with.

```
vector<double> haar1d(vector<double> vec, double seriesAverage)
{
vector<double> transVec(vec.size(), 0);
vector<double>::size_type length = vec.size();

if(vec[0] == seriesAverage)
{
    return vec;
}

int diffFromAvgs = length / 2;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
{
    double pairAverage = (vec[i] + vec[i + 1]) / 2;
    transVec[i] = pairAverage;
    transVec[diffFromAvgs+i] = vec[i] - pairAverage;
}

return haar1d(transVec, seriesAverage);
}
```

in main:

```
vector<double> result = haar1d(series, avg);

for(vector<double>::iterator it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << ",";
}
```

Comment: Post your function.

Comment: `<<` does not modify values. There is something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: returning a pointer to a local object produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @PeteBecker, That's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: (hairsplitting follows) Actually, `<<` modifies it's left hand side argument, the stream.

Comment: << is an overload. If it is not overloaded correctly it will change values.

Comment: @xis19 We're talking about `std::ostream::operator<<(double)`.  We know what that one does, and it doesn't change any values.  (It takes the double by copy, so it can't, even if it tried.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `operator<<` does not modify its arguments. It prints them as is. However, I bet your function looks something like this:

```
double* haar1d(/* ... */)
{
  double arr[N];
  // Fill this array
  return arr;
}
```

The point being that the array `arr` is local to the function. It will be destroyed when the function ends. However, you're returning a pointer to its first element. That pointer will be invalid outside the function, because the array it points to has been destroyed. To use this pointer now will invoke undefined behaviour, so you shouldn't be surprised if values start changing seemingly randomly.

I recommend using either `std::array<double, N>` or `std::vector<double>`, depending on whether your array size is a compile time constant or not. Returning either of these will copy its contents to the calling function.

If I'm guessing correctly, you might be using the argument that you gave as `2` as the size of the array. If this is compiling, you are using a compiler with a variable length arrays extension, and your code is not standard C++.

Comment: Ahh.  Yeah that's definitely it.  I thought about that earlier but seeing the value of the undefined area evaluate to "3.30525e+230" over and over again I dismissed that.